# Invoke lambda function using aurora DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, entity-framework, aws-lambda

The project I'm working on requires creating an DB aurora (PostgreSQL) that will send request to a lambda function (After every insert to X table) and the lambda function invoke a step function.

Aurora > Lambda > Step Function > Lambda

So the question : How can I invoke (and sent data) to my lambda function and after that invoke the step function in every insert to my X table? (I am open to any solutions)

I'm using asp.net and C# and i want to use EF with the step function to do "Select Data".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the question : How can I invoke (and sent data) to my lambda function

Follow [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Lambda.html) to trigger a Lambda function from Aurora. It shows examples of sending payload data from Aurora to the Lambda function.

> and after that invoke the step function in every insert to my X table?

Just use the AWS SDK in the Lambda function to [call StartExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html) on your Step Function. In C#, that would be [this method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/StepFunctions/MStepFunctionsStartExecutionStartExecutionRequest.html).